# my trigger error in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am creating a trigger on the table below,

```html
CREATE TRIGGER absen_jam
AFTER INSERT ON logfinjer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM logfinjer,doskar_usm 
WHERE logfinjer.id_finjer=doskar_usm.id_finjer 
AND doskar_usm.id_absain='1' ;
    IF NEW.jam BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '07:45:59'
 
 THEN    
    INSERT INTO absen(id_finjer,keterangan,jam,potongan)VALUES
     (new.id_finjer,'masuk',new.jam,'0');


END IF;

end;
```

my trigger error

```html
[Err] 1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
```

Pls tell me what is wrong here:
thanks

Comment: is this part necessary ? `SELECT * FROM logfinjer,doskar_usm 
WHERE logfinjer.id_finjer=doskar_usm.id_finjer`

Comment: You cannot return a result set from a trigger.

Comment: Can you provide a solution sir, please

Answer (score 0):

I think that "select" query is not allowed there. I am not pretty sure what are you trying to do with this trigger containing that select.